# OpenGL GLSL Log

Tags: opengl

I am trying to learn shaders in OpenGL. I wrote some shader code which is incorrect, and attempted to compile it using this:

```
    GLint compiled;
    char *infoLog;
    GLsizei length;

    FILE *fd;

    neuronFragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(neuronFragmentShader,1,neuronFragmentShaderSource,NULL);
    glCompileShader(neuronFragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv(neuronFragmentShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&compiled);
    if(compiled){
            printf("Fragment Shader compiled successfully\n");
    }else{
            printf("Fragment Shader failed to compile\n");
            glGetShaderiv(neuronFragmentShader,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&length);
            printf("Log length: %d\n",length);
            infoLog = malloc(length);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(neuronFragmentShader,length,&length,infoLog);
            fd = fopen("log.txt","w");
            fwrite(infoLog,1,length,fd);
            fclose(fd);
            free(infoLog);
    }
```

The result was that I am shown that the log length was 4198256. However, looking at log.txt, I see it is blank. I want to know how to properly access the log for compilation of a shader after attempting a compile. How do I do this?

Comment: do you even have a valid GL context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you're stating there indicates about 4MiB of log data. That'd be a very long log (maybe C++ compile error logs can get that big, but GLSL probably not). I suspect that the length you see there is some leftover garbage left in the `length` variable not being initialized. Similarly you didn't initialize the `compiled` variable. And because you don't check for OpenGL errors (`glGetError`) you don't really know if your OpenGL calls actually did anything or not. OpenGL functions bail out early and don't touch memory pointed to if there's an error.

Initialize your variables to recognizable states and make sure OpenGL actually does something (i.e. check glGetError).

Comment: You were correct, no error log is being generated. The "neuronFragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);" call seems to be failing, so the getLog function doesn't work because there is no log.